# Heroku Django application slower after moving postgres database to Amazon free RDS

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, amazon-web-services

I have a pilot Django project installed on Heroku using the free tier and the free Postgres database. However due to the size limitation on Heroku, I moved the database to Amazon RDS free tier which offers a lot more space and no row limit.
However after the move I notice a very slow performance in my Django app! Is there a way to reconfigure my setup to make my application/database go faster?

Comment: which region did you created the RDS instance?

Take into account that Heroku operates on EU and US regions, but only 1 AWS location for each heroku region.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions#data-center-locations

You must be creating the RDS in us-east-1 or eu-west-1 for us and eu location, respectively.

Comment: I didn't have a lot choice, so I picked us-west-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the "free tier" of RDS, you are using a very small database (in terms of CPU and memory) so it shouldn't come as a surprise that it is slow. Specifically, the free tier is a t2.micro, which has one virtual CPU and 1gb of memory.

Also, your storage type (magnetic, ssd, provisioned iops) may make a substantial difference. You can observe the disk stats in cloudwatch for the RDS instance to see if that's the problem.